# SQL-Statement for counting occurrences groupewise

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to run a sql query to get the rows of one table and the number of references to it from another table. However the number of references should be splitt, by a field in the second table.

Here is my simplified DB-Schema

```
TableA             TableB
------             ------
ID                 FK_A
                   GroupId
```

I want to query for TableA and count the referencing elements of TableB, but **grouping** them because of their GroupId. A result may look like this (`Group1`, `Group2` and `Group3` are the values inside TableB.GroupId):

```
SELECT ID, ??? FROM TableA

ID Group1 Group2 Group3
1  1      0      7
2  3      3      9
```

I should count all of the occurrences in TableB, that reference my TableA.

I don't really know how to make the subquery or whatever is needed here.

**UPDATE**
I do not know, which GroupIds can be in TableB. So multiple count statements aren't working.

Comment: are there fixed number of groups?

Comment: no, which is the big problem here

Answer (score 0):

Use `Conditional Aggregate`

```
select FK_A,
       Count(case when GroupId = 1 then 1 end) as Group1,
       Count(case when GroupId = 2 then 1 end) as Group2,
       Count(case when GroupId = 3 then 1 end) as Group3
From TableB
Group by FK_A
```

If the number of Groups are unknown then

```
DECLARE @col VARCHAR(8000)= (SELECT ',' + Quotename(GroupId)
   FROM   TableB
   GROUP  BY GroupId
   FOR xml path (''))

SET @col = Stuff(@col, 1, 1, '')

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000)='select * from TableB pivot (count(GroupId) for GroupId in ('
 + @col + ')) pv'

EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: I do not know which group ids are in TableB. They don't have to be integers either...

Comment: @Karl - second approach should work for you